# How to declare this vector correctly?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I want to use an array (of size `count`) of three fields - a long `a`, an int vector of length 9 named `b` and a bool `c`.

What is the right way to declare it?

Declaration 1:

```
vector <long a, vector<int> b(9), bool c> matrix(count);
```

Errors:

```
code.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
code.cpp:89:49: error: template argument 1 is invalid
code.cpp:89:49: error: template argument 2 is invalid
code.cpp:89:57: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘(’ token
```

Declaration 2:

```
vector <long, vector<int>, bool> matrix(count, a, vector<int> b(9), c);
```

Errors:

```
code.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
code.cpp:90:40: error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 2)
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_vector.h:170:11: error: provided for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
code.cpp:90:48: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘(’ token
code.cpp:90:56: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
code.cpp:90:71: error: expected primary-expression before ‘b’
code.cpp:90:77: error: ‘c’ was not declared in this scope
code.cpp:90:78: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
```

I an new to STL and am not sure what is the right syntax here?

Comment: I am not clear about what you are trying to do but If you want 3 fields in every object then you will have to create a structure and which has those 3 fields as members and then you store the objects of the structure in the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STL templates, usually, take only one parameter determining a type of contained data (and there is always a fixed number of parameters).

To get the expected effect you have to create a structure

```
struct s
{
  long a;
  std::vector<int> b;
  bool c;

  s(); // Declared default constructor, see below
};
```

and create a vector of objects of type `s`;

```
std::vector<s> matrix(count);
```

In order to initialize objects contained in a structure you have iterate over a vector and assign them manually, or declare a default contructor.

```
s::s()
: b(9) // after the colon, you can pass the constructor
// parameters for objects cointained in a structure.
{
  a = 0;
  c = false;
}
```

Comment: There is not always a fixed number of tempalte argument, std::tuple<...> is variadic.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Fields {
  long a;
  std::array<int, 9> b, 
  bool c;
};

std::vector<Fields> matrix(count);
```

or

```
std::vector<std::tuple<long, std::array<int, 9>, bool> > matrix(count);
```

Comment: Don't I need to do a `typedef` on `Fields` before using it like this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. One of them is create a `struct` like below and create a `std::vector<>` using this `struct`:

```
struct vector_elem_type
{
   long a;
   std::vector<int> b;
   bool c;
};

//vector of vector_elem_type
std::vector< struct vector_elem_type > v(9);
```

Another way is to use [`boost::tuple`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#using_library).

```
// vector of tuples
std::vector< boost::tuple< long, std::vector<int>, bool > v(9);

// accessing the tuple elements    
long l = get<0>(v[0]);
std::vector<int> vi = get<1>(v[0]);
bool b = get<2>(v[0]);
```

For more details on boost::tuple click on the link above.